# How to Show data of Two Tables in a Report Viewer

Tags: sql, dataset, datatables, reportviewer, multiple-tables

I am facing problem while displaying data of two tables in report viewer.

It was working well when it show data from single table but i want to display some other detail from another table in report viewer.

I want to show data of two tables in report viewer.

How can I achieve this requirement.
Thanks

Comment: Join the two tables in the query that generates your dataset.

Comment: how to join two tables  if i created a datatable and fill it by pragmatically.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question.